# TornadoFX How to create MDI with list of child windows models?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I have following components:

```
class ChildModel:ViewModel() { //or it may be an POJO, it does not matter
  val value ....      
} 

class ParentView: View() {
  ...
  //Maybe this should be implemented into ParentViewModel   
  val childrenList:List<ChildModel>

  fun addFragmentAsChild() {
    //should:
    // 1. display fragment within ParentView
    // 2. add fragment into modelList (or fragmentList - it does not matter -  important to have access to the model of every child )  
  }

  fun deleteFragmentAsChild() {
    //should destroy child and remove item from childrenList   
    //should work also on manual closing 
  }         
}

class ChildFragment: Fragment() {
  val model = ChildModel()      
...
}
```

Summary: I want to create MDI and have access to model for every child.

I try do this with help "openInternalWindow" , but i can't create multiple child instances and i must manually manage the list - it's bad.

```
class InstrumentsView: View() {
  override val root = BorderPane()
  val instrumentList = ArrayList<InstrumentFragment>()

  init {
    with(root){
      top = menubar {
        menu("Tools") {
          menuitem("Add instrument", "Shortcut+A") {
            val newFragment = InstrumentFragment()
            instrumentList.add(newFragment)
            println(instrumentList.size)
            openInternalWindow(newFragment, modal = false)
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to do it right tornadofx way?

Comment: Do you want access to the actual fragments, or do you just want a list of the models they contain, and that list should update as you open/close fragment editors? Should each InstrumentFragment manage it's own/separate instrument? PS: Never instantiate a Fragment directly, use find, inject or `this += InstrumentFragment`.

Comment: I need access to list of the models (ofcource, i can also get reference on the model, if i will have list of the fragments - me the most important is clean and elegant solution ) and i want update this list after  open/close fragment editors. Each IntrumentFragment only knows about his model (or have a reference to the parent - why not?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example I'll use a view model and scoping to keep track of the item for each instrument editor. We need to make sure the instruments are unique so we can remove them from the list when the editor is closed. I created an `Instrument` domain object with an id and a name:

```
class Instrument {
    val idProperty = SimpleObjectProperty<UUID>(UUID.randomUUID())
    var id by idProperty

    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty()
    var name by nameProperty

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other?.javaClass != javaClass) return false

        other as Instrument

        if (id != other.id) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return id.hashCode()
    }
}
```

We want a view model we can inject in the instrument editor. We'll make sure the view model contains a new instrument by default. It contains a facade for the name property so we can bind it to an editor input field.

```
class InstrumentModel: ItemViewModel<Instrument>() {
    init {
        item = Instrument()
        item.name = "New instrument"
    }
    val name = bind { item?.nameProperty }
}
```

A `Fragment` has callbacks for `onDock` and `onUndock` which can be used to keep track of the model for that fragment. We can use events to signal this. Declare the following events:

```
class InstrumentAdded(val instrument: Instrument) : FXEvent()
class InstrumentRemoved(val instrument: Instrument) : FXEvent()
```

Override the docking callbacks in `InstrumentFragment` to fire these events:

```
override fun onDock() {
    fire(InstrumentAdded(model.item))
}

override fun onUndock() {
    fire(InstrumentRemoved(model.item))
}
```

For now we'll keep the list of instruments in the main view, `InstrumentsView`. This could just as well be in a `Controller`.

```
val instruments = FXCollections.observableArrayList<Instrument>()
```

In the init class of the main view, we'll subscribe to the events we created and modify our list:

```
subscribe<InstrumentAdded> {
    instruments.add(it.instrument)
}
subscribe<InstrumentRemoved> {
    instruments.remove(it.instrument)
}
```

The "New Instrument" action will open a new InstrumentEditor in a new `Scope` so we can inject the view model into it and get an instance unique to that editor.

```
menuitem("Add instrument", "Shortcut+A") {
    find<InstrumentFragment>(Scope()).openWindow()
}
```

Unfortunately, we can't use `openInternalWindow` as it currently only supports one internal window at a time. Therefore I used `openWindow` instead.

If you want to close the editor from an action, you can call `closeModal()` from anywhere inside the fragment.

I've included a complete example app with a TableView that shows the currently open instruments. It will look like the image below. Notice that you need to hit save before the changes are flushed from the model and visible in the table.
[image: sample app]

I hope this is what you're looking for, or that you at least can modify it to fit your use case based on this sample.

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty
import javafx.collections.FXCollections
import tornadofx.*
import java.util.*

class Instrument {
    val idProperty = SimpleObjectProperty<UUID>(UUID.randomUUID())
    var id by idProperty

    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty()
    var name by nameProperty

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other?.javaClass != javaClass) return false

        other as Instrument

        if (id != other.id) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return id.hashCode()
    }
}

class InstrumentModel : ItemViewModel<Instrument>() {
    init {
        item = Instrument()
        item.name = "New instrument"
    }

    val name = bind { item?.nameProperty }
}

class InstrumentAdded(val instrument: Instrument) : FXEvent()
class InstrumentRemoved(val instrument: Instrument) : FXEvent()

class InstrumentFragment : Fragment("Instrument Editor") {
    val model: InstrumentModel by inject()

    override val root = form {
        prefWidth = 300.0
        fieldset("Edit instrument") {
            field("Name") {
                textfield(model.name)
            }
        }
        button("Save") {
            setOnAction {
                model.commit()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDock() {
        fire(InstrumentAdded(model.item))
    }

    override fun onUndock() {
        fire(InstrumentRemoved(model.item))
    }
}

class InstrumentsView : View() {
    val instruments = FXCollections.observableArrayList<Instrument>()

    override val root = borderpane {
        setPrefSize(400.0, 300.0)
        top {
            menubar {
                menu("Tools") {
                    menuitem("Add instrument", "Shortcut+A") {
                        find<InstrumentFragment>(Scope()).openWindow()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        center {
            tableview(instruments) {
                column("Name", Instrument::nameProperty)
                columnResizePolicy = SmartResize.POLICY
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        subscribe<InstrumentAdded> {
            instruments.add(it.instrument)
        }
        subscribe<InstrumentRemoved> {
            instruments.remove(it.instrument)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Edvin! This what i want! I've never used "Scope" and "EventBus" functionality. It is necessary to learn.

Comment: Happy to hear it :) We have added Scope and EventBus to the guide if you want to read about it there: https://www.gitbook.com/book/edvin/tornadofx-guide/details