# How to add an MDI parent in tornadofx

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I try to make a MDI form but not successful, it always over old windows, so how can we make an MDI form under menubar, what should i do to replace this code to show as an MDI form

[TornadoFX How to create MDI with list of child windows models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466441/tornadofx-how-to-create-mdi-with-list-of-child-windows-models)

```
center {
  tableview(instruments) {
    column("Name", Instrument::nameProperty)
    columnResizePolicy = SmartResize.POLICY
  }
}
```

This is what i have:
[MyForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czAfF.png)

after i click on menu item, new form will show and i want it under menubar but i can't do that

Answer (score 0):

create a variable for yourView

```
private val yourMainView: YourMainView by inject()
private val yourNewView: YourNewView by inject()
```

```
menuitem {
  setOnMouseClicked { 
    find<YourMainView>().replaceWith(YourNewView::class)
  }
}
```

```
center { 
   add(yourMainView.root)
}
```

this will add the view and its elements to your center ;)

Comment: i hope this is what you want :)?

Comment: sorry when i late answer, thank you very much it rather helpful for me. but it not really what i want. i want it same as C# MDI, with your issue i can't close newView it only replace oldview

Comment: what do you mean with close exactly i dont know how that works in C#

Comment: do you want to have it as own window?

Comment: Thanks for your care, i has been made it by using DesktopPane, it stiil not work perfect but resolve my needed